# How to use wildcard * with graphicspath in LaTeX?

Tags: latex, wildcard

How can you have the wildcard character, for example in the following code?

```
\graphicspath{{1/*/pictures/}}
```

Comment: No on SuperUser. I end up writing versions of this a lot, but LaTeX is a Turing complete language. The problem here is to get find a *syntax* for desired output without endlessly coping. If Will Robertson bothers, he can probably show us how to write the loop. If nyou solve it with a loop, it is programming.

Comment: @dmckee: I'm not arguing that this isn't programming related, but it will attract a broader range of people on SU. LaTeX users are not necessarily programmers.

Comment: @Bastien: This is a question whose intended audience — those it expects to attract answers from — are LaTeX users who *are* programmers. This is no different from questions about specific programming languages (say JavaScript)

Comment: Same for `input`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13921/inputting-multiple-files-in-latex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use wildcards with `\graphicspath`.  You'll have to be explicit:

```
\graphicspath{{1/pictures/}{2/pictures/}{3/pictures/}{...etc...}}
```

I found the [LaTeX Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/) a few months ago.  It's a good reference for getting started.

Comment: @Sean: Thank you Sean! - I knew that the problem was somewhere as I asked this question. - My PATHs are long. This made me to use the following syntax `\graphicspath{{very-long-path1}}; \graphicspath{{very-long-path2}}; in separate lines. - Your example is the key to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that wildcards can't be used within the `\graphicspath` command. However, you can use a workaround based on a bash script if you are running a Unix based OS.

In your example, you can create a script named *myGraphicspath.sh*:

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH="./1/*/pictures"

echo -n \\graphicspath{{./}

for i in $PATH; do
    echo -n \{$i/\}
done

echo \}
```

Put that script in the same folder as your *.tex*.
Now, you can call that script from Latex. Where you would have placed the `\graphicspath` command, now you type:

```
\immediate\write18{./myGraphicspath.sh > myGraphicspath.tex}
\input{myGraphicspath.tex}
```